# RESTFul API : create method doesn't execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a restful api, following this [Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/webapi-restful-operations-in-webapi-using-ado-net-objects-a/)

The thing is, when calling the link to get a object, it works :

```
[HttpGet]
        [ActionName("GetDemByID")]
```

But when I tried to call this one :

```
[HttpPost]
        [ActionName("CreateDemByID")]
```

I got a 405 errors.

My router seems to be ok :

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Am I missing something to have a full CRUD REST api?
I don't even go through the method in debug mode...

[Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) I see that ActionName is also usable for a post method, so it is not a problem in the method, but with the router, or the annotations...

Is there better tutorial (using action name, and without EF) thant the one I actually used?

**Edit :** As suggested, it was simply due to the call, made in Get.

Using RESTClient to tests in the browser, it allow me to choose the kind of method I want to use, and it works fine now.

A module is really helpful when making a REST Api. I was thinking it would not be necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the `url` you're requesting to?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I request http://localhost:50050/api/demindividuelles/GetDemByID for the first and http://localhost:50050/api/demindividuelles/CreateDemByID for the second.

Comment: show your `Action` signature and how are you calling the action.If Fiddler works,there's some other problem in your calling code.

Comment: Show your controller signature and how you are calling it..

Answer (score 1):

for the HTTP Request use this in your Ajax request

```
Content-type: application/json
```